# CakePHP: Join Operation not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, join

I have Tables

```
Items, Attributes,Taxonomies, Taxonomy_attributes,Item_attributes.
```

Taxonomy_attributes have two fields attribute_id(which is a foreign key to id of attributes table) and taxonomy_id (which is a foreign key to id of taxonomies table).
On the other hand Item_attributes have two fields attribute_id(which is a foreign key to id attributes table) and item_id (which is a foreign key to of id items table).
Attributes table have following fields :- Name, Type and Checkable(which is either 0 or 1).
Items table have fields id and model.
Taxonomies table have fields if and name.

I want to  add a method to Attribute model ,that returns list of all attributes with checkable equals 1 and join with items and taxonomies ,that return item model & taxonomy name for each attribute.

My code is as follows:-

```
public function getCheckables($checkable)
{
    $data =  $this->find('all',array(
                'fields' => array('Attribute.name', 'Attribute.type', 'Item.model', 'Taxonomy.name'),
                'conditions' => array('Attribute.checkable' => 1),
                'joins' =>  array(
                            array(
                                 'table' => 'item_attributes',
                                'alias' => 'ItemAttribute',
                                'type' => 'INNER',
                                'conditions' => 'ItemAttribute.Item_id = Item.id',
                             ),
                             array( 
                                'table' => 'items',
                                'alias' => 'Item',
                                'type' => 'INNER',
                                'conditions' => 'ItemAttribute.item_id = Item.id'
                            ),
                             array( 
                                'table' => 'taxonomy_attributes',
                                'alias' => 'TaxonomyAttribute',
                                'type' => 'INNER',
                                'conditions' => 'TaxonomyAttribute.Taxonomy_id = Taxonomy.id'
                            )

                    ),
                    'recursive'=>-1
                )
                );  
                pr($data); die();   
}
```

Can anybody guide me with the right code?

Comment: do you have any kind of relationship defined in your model with the other 3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 of your joins have the same condition : 'conditions' => 'ItemAttribute.Item_id = Item.id', in case of the first one, Item table was not yet joined and in case of the second one, because your first condition was wrong, the ItemAttribute table was not joined.

Comment: You are right. Both joins are having same condition. but there are some other problem too. I am accepting your answer because your answer is correct. @Tanatos

Answer (score 0):

## The actual Solution

```
public function getCheckables($checkable)
    {
        $data =  $this->find('all',array(
                    'fields' => array('Attribute.name', 'Attribute.type', 'Item.model', 'Taxonomy.name'),
                    'conditions' => array('Attribute.checkable' => 1),
                    'joins' =>  array(

                                 array(
                                     'table' => 'item_attributes',
                                    'alias' => 'ItemAttribute',
                                    'type' => 'INNER',
                                    'conditions' => 'ItemAttribute.attribute_id = Attribute.id',
                                 ),
                                 array( 
                                    'table' => 'items',
                                    'alias' => 'Item',
                                    'type' => 'INNER',
                                    'conditions' => 'ItemAttribute.item_id = Item.id'
                                ),
                                  array( 
                                    'table' => 'taxonomies',
                                    'alias' => 'Taxonomy',
                                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                                    'conditions' => 'Item.category_id = Item.id'
                                )



                        ),
                        'recursive'=>-1
                    )
                    );  
                    pr($data); die();   
    }
```